# How to query Postgis database to pull all user coordinates from one table, within a polygon from another

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a Postgis database with polygons in a geom::geometry column. I have table with a 'point' type column of coordinates. I want to pull all of the user_coordinates rows where their coordinate is found within a specific polygon.

I've been researching answers on stackoverflow for days. I've tried all sorts of queries (ST_Contains, ST_Within), most of them telling me that a function I know exists, doesn't. I think it's being thrown off by the point I'm giving it, and wonder what format or type the point column should be in.

Here's a query I'm attempting to give you an idea of what I'm after...

```sql
select u.user_id 
from electorial_boundries as e 
INNER JOIN user_coordinates as u on
   ST_Contains(e.geom,ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(u.user_coor))) 
where e.org_id = 595
```

////Additionally as requested

What is expect:

List all the rows from user_coordinates where the coordinate in user_coordinates.user_coor shows up in the selected polygon from electorial_boundries.geom

Here is the sql for the tables...(sorry, I'm not familiar with how best to use fiddle)

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.user_coordinates
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    user_coor point NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_coordinates_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE public.electorial_boundries
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('electorial_boundries_id_seq'::regclass),
    data_id bigint,
    geom geometry(MultiPolygon,4326),
    district_name character(120) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT electorial_boundries_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

The errors are I get that "Function (ST_Contains or ST_Within) Does not exist". But it seems it's just conflicted by the point I'm trying to give it, as an actual coordinate in place of u.user_coor yields some results, though not limited to users in the polygon.

Comment: Welcome to SO. ST_Contains should do the job, but it is hard to tell without more information. Please add some sample data as `create table` and `insert` statements (preferably in a fiddle) and the exact expected result of your query. Your query has some syntax problems... so I wonder if you got any error message?

Comment: Thank for helping guide me down the write path of stackoverflow. I hope these edits help explain my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column `user_coor` is of type `point`, which is a [native postgres type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html#id-1.5.7.16.5) that is **not** directly usable with PostGIS functions.

The error message likely tells you that `function ST_Contains(geometry, point) does not exist`, which highlights the wrong "point" type as the function exists for two geometries only.

If you can, you should change the column definition to be of type `geometry(point,4326)`.

You can however cast the `point` to a `geometry`

```sql
select u.user_id 
from electorial_boundries as e 
INNER JOIN user_coordinates as u on
   ST_Contains(e.geom, u.user_coor::geometry) 
where e.org_id = 595
```

Comment: Thank you JGH, I changed the column type to Geom, and inserted the coordinates with ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-79.834401 43.251856)', 4326) and everything worked great! And thanks for showing me the correct structured  way to post code on stack!